# Objective-C – Difference in app startup methods from iOS 4 to iOS 5?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios4, ios5

I have developed my app initially for iOS 4 and now that iOS 5 is out I decided to develop for the iOS 5 SDK which now seems to have broken my app.

I have a tab bar application with a navigation controller in each tab.

In iOS 4 everything that was in the `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method was executed first after startup. After that method was executed, the view controller for the first tab was loaded.

So when I log my startup app process (running the simulator for **iOS 4.3**) it looks like this:

```
-[AcandoAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] [Line 35] didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method running
-[AcandoAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] [Line 60] This should be executed first // And it does as it should
-[AcandoAppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:] [Line 254] applicationDidBecomeActive method running
-[SeminarsViewController viewDidLoad] [Line 58] 2 - viewDidLoad method running
-[SeminarsViewController viewDidLoad] [Line 60] This should be executed second // Also as it should
-[SeminarsViewController viewWillAppear:] [Line 123] 3 - viewWillAppear method running
-[SeminarsViewController viewDidAppear:] [Line 173] viewDidAppear running
```

Now when I log my startup app process (running the simulator for **iOS 5.0**) it looks like this:

```
-[AcandoAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] [Line 35] didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method running
-[SeminarsViewController viewDidLoad] [Line 58] 2 - viewDidLoad method running
-[SeminarsViewController viewDidLoad] [Line 60] This should be executed second // So this should be executed second but is executed first
-[SeminarsViewController viewWillAppear:] [Line 123] 3 - viewWillAppear method running
-[AcandoAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] [Line 60] This should be executed first // And this is executed second but should be executed first
-[AcandoAppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:] [Line 254] applicationDidBecomeActive method running
-[SeminarsViewController viewDidAppear:] [Line 173] viewDidAppear running
```

Am I missing something obvious here? For me it looks like we have two different startup situations between iOS 4 and iOS 5?

Comment: If you test this multiple times, are the results the same?

Comment: Yes results are same every time. Is the handling of .xib files (MainWindow.xib in my case) different in iOS 5 compared to iOS 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does the successful startup of your app depend on a particular sequence of these events? There should be nothing in those sequences above which cause you issue, your code should be oblivious as to the exact underlying startup sequence.

Can you give some code to explain WHY this is causing you an issue?

Comment: I'm initializing some objects in the `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method that I depend on should be initialized BEFORE loading the view controller (SeminarsViewController) in the first tab. That's why the startup is "successfull" (my code works as it was intended to) in iOS 4, but the exact same code is working differently i iOS 5. So somehow they have changed something in the way `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` works from iOS 4 to iOS 5.

Comment: Ahh ok. I would tend to hook up your view controller via code rather than Interface Builder, it will give you total control over when the view controller is created (and subsequent view loaded).

Comment: But why does My code behave differently depending if it's run on iOS 4 or iOS 5?

Comment: Unsure, we have noticed differences due to performance of device too, so on older devices the ordering of certain calls is different than newer ones (even on the same OS), this is most likely due to the threading of the core libraries. The main thing is to try to make your code run regardless of a specific ordering.

Comment: Seemed like what was the best option was to hook everything up programatically to ensure full control since the .XIB loading process seems to have changed between iOS4 and iOS5. No more MainView.xib for me.